Closed form for arithmetico geometric recursion

Henry decides one morning to do a workout, and he walks $\tfrac{3}{4}$
of the way from his home to his gym. The gym is $2$ kilometers away
from Henry's home. At that point, he changes his mind and walks
$\tfrac{3}{4}$ of the way from where he is back toward home. When he
reaches that point, he changes his mind again and walks $\tfrac{3}{4}$
of the distance from there back toward the gym. If Henry keeps
changing his mind when he has walked $\tfrac{3}{4}$ of the distance
toward either the gym or home from the point where he last changed his
mind, he will get very close to walking back and forth between a point
$A$ kilometers from home and a point $B$ kilometers from home. What is
$|A-B|$? (AMC 10B 2019/18)

Solution 5 derives an arithmetico geometric recursion:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{16}a_{n-1}+\frac{3}{8}$$
and then applies the "standard procedure to convert this arithmetico geometric recursion into a closed form" which requires letting, for some constant $k$ to be determined:
$$a_n - k = \frac{1}{16}(a_{n-1}-k)$$
I understand the other parts of the question and solution. My question is with this respect to this standard procedure. I know that we can assume convergence of the sequence. How/why do we know that the first recursion must also be a recursion of the second form?

Say you have $a_{n+1} = sa_n +m$ with $s<1$, you can do some algebra and write it as $$a_{n+1} +\frac{m}{s-1} = s\left( a_n +\frac{m}{s-1}\right). $$
If $s<1$ convergence is obvious, we let $b_n = a_n + \tfrac{m}{s-1}$ and see that $b_n \to 0$ exponentially fast, so $a_n \to \tfrac{-m}{s-1}$ exponentially fast as well.
